# How to find mean and standard deviation for each chunks of a list by using python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find the mean and standard deviation for different chunks of a list. But I failed to find the appropriate way. Is there anyone who can suggest me the way to find it? Input and output will be as follows. I need to find the mean and standard deviation for sublist. It would be really great if someone suggests me an appropriate code to do this.

Input and Output will be as follows:

```
Data = [[2.60, 7.80, 6.60, 1.20, 6.50, 7.40, 9.30], [3.10, 2.20, 2.40, 9.20, 1.50, 1.50, 4.90], [12.00, 7.80, 2.30, 1.00, 1.50, 11.40, 13.90], [6.80, 13.70, 12.40, 2.60,   5.00, 13.50, 10.90], [16.60, 16.70, 11.20, 20.00, 19.50, 18.50, 17.40], [16.10, 16.70, 18.10, 14.60, 6.60, 4.00, 15.00]]
```

Output:

```
mean = [5.91, 3.54, 7.13, 9.27, 17.13, 13.01]
standard_dev = [2.92, 2.75, 5.49, 4.45, 2.93, 5.44]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import statistics 

Data = [[2.60, 7.80, 6.60, 1.20, 6.50, 7.40, 9.30], [3.10, 2.20, 2.40, 9.20, 1.50, 1.50, 4.90], [12.00, 7.80, 2.30, 1.00, 1.50, 11.40, 13.90], [6.80, 13.70, 12.40, 2.60,   5.00, 13.50, 10.90], [16.60, 16.70, 11.20, 20.00, 19.50, 18.50, 17.40], [16.10, 16.70, 18.10, 14.60, 6.60, 4.00, 15.00]]

mean = [statistics.mean(d) for d in Data]
stdev = [statistics.stdev(d) for d in Data]
```